# Is it possible to adjust the distance between data points and data labels with pixels instead of axes values in gpplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Hello below I provide a scater plot which as you can see displaes the type of the car for every data point. This plot is static so `nudge_x=0.05` fits nicely. In my case the plot is updated so the axes range can be from 0 to 10 to 0 to 10000. At this case the 0.05 distance seems useless because it is very small value compared to 10000 and the data label is displayed on the data point. I was wondering if instead of 0.05 I could set the distance to pixels or something else that would keep the distance between data point and data label unaffected by the the axes values.

```
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))
    p + geom_point() + geom_text(hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.05)
```

my actual code:

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel(div("CROSS CORRELATION",style = "color:blue")),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Input CSV-File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),


      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")





    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Table",
                           shiny::dataTableOutput("contents")),
                  tabPanel("Correlation Plot",
                           tags$style(type="text/css", "
           #loadmessage {
                                      position: fixed;
                                      top: 0px;
                                      left: 0px;
                                      width: 100%;
                                      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                                      text-align: center;
                                      font-weight: bold;
                                      font-size: 100%;
                                      color: #000000;
                                      background-color: #CCFF66;
                                      z-index: 105;
                                      }
                                      "),conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                                                          tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")
                                      ),
                           fluidRow(
                             column(3, uiOutput("lx1")),
                           column(3,uiOutput("lx2"))),
                           hr(),
                           fluidRow(
                             tags$style(type="text/css",
                                        ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                                        ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                             ),
                           column(3,uiOutput("td")),
                           column(3,uiOutput("an"))),
                           fluidRow(
                           plotlyOutput("sc"))
      ))
  )))
#server.r
function(input, output) {


  output$contents <- shiny::renderDataTable({

    iris
  })


  output$lx1<-renderUI({
    selectInput("lx1", label = h4("Select 1st Expression Profile"), 
                choices = colnames(iris[,1:4]), 
                selected = "Lex1")
  })
  output$lx2<-renderUI({
    selectInput("lx2", label = h4("Select 2nd Expression Profile"), 
                choices = colnames(iris[,1:4]), 
                selected = "Lex2")
  })

  output$td<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("td", label = h4("Trendline"),
                 choices = list("Add Trendline" = "lm", "Remove Trendline" = ""), 
                 selected = "")
  })

  output$an<-renderUI({

    radioButtons("an", label = h4("Correlation Coefficient"),
                 choices = list("Add Cor.Coef" = cor(subset(iris, select=c(input$lx1)),subset(iris, select=c(input$lx2))), "Remove Cor.Coef" = ""), 
                 selected = "")
  })  


 output$sc<-renderPlotly({

   p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$lx1, y = input$lx2))+

     # Change the point options in geom_point
     geom_point(color = "darkblue") +
     # Change the title of the plot (can change axis titles
     # in this option as well and add subtitle)
     labs(title = "Cross Correlation") +
     # Change where the tick marks are
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 2.5, 30)) +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 2.5, 30)) +
     # Change how the text looks for each element
     theme(title = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                size = 10, 
                                face = "bold"), 
           axis.title = element_text(family = "Calibri Light", 
                                     size = 16, 
                                     face = "bold", 
                                     color = "darkgrey"), 
           axis.text = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                    size = 11))+
     theme_bw()+
     geom_smooth(method = input$td)+
     annotate("text", x = 10, y = 10, label = as.character(input$an))
   ggplotly(p1) %>%
     layout(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white", 
                              font = list(family = "Calibri", 
                                          size = 9, 
                                          color = "black")))

 }) 




}
```

Comment: You can also go the other way and take the range of your x-axis, multiply this by a factor, e.g., 0.05. That way your `nudge_x` can adjust to the x and y variables you choose

Comment: Use `hjust` - it will adjust based on the length of the text. Try `hjust = -0.05` instead of 0.

Comment: hjust instead of nudge_x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hjust` instead of `nudge_x`. Where `nudge_x` works in plot units, `hjust` is made for horizontally justifying the text by adjusting where it starts. A value of 0 is left justified, 0.5 is centered, and a value of 1 is right justified:

```
       Point where text starts:
       |
       |Hjust 0
Hjust 1|
```

You can use any value. A negative value will move the starting letter *even farther* to the right than a value of 0 for left justification, and this adjustment is based on the length of the text, not on the plot coordinates.

It's a little weird because longer strings will move more, but as an easy hack it works pretty well. This won't matter much unless you have very different string lengths. You can see it a little bit in this example comparing "Fiat 128" to "Toyota Corolla".

See the similar results for the same `hjust` value even though `wt` and `hp` differ by about a factor of 100:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_point() + geom_text(hjust = -.05)

q <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))
q + geom_point() + geom_text(hjust = -.05)
```

Comment: for some reason it does not work with my actual code so i editted

Comment: Probably a `plotly` issue.

Comment: I guess so...any alternative ?